# SSH and Telnet library for java

Tags: java, ssh, telnet

I'm building a Java application who connects to hosts using telnet or ssh, execute a command and then return the output.

I've been using org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient and written my own parsers so far. But I want to work less and do more.

Can someone recommend any SSH or telnet libraries that is easy to configure and use? 
It would be great if have some sort of expect functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) it is good for telnet and ssh related stuff.

Comment: Just for info: Jsh is also featured in apache ants telnet target.

Comment: does JSch support Telnet. I dont think it does!

Comment: @ayush is correct, the JSch **[does NOT support the Telnet protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35558374/850848)**.

Answer (score 0):

[JTelnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtelnet/)