# Telnet support in JSch

Tags: java, telnet, jsch

I'm currently building a Java application which will connect to a switch using Telnet or SSH. I'm currently using the JSch for the SSH connection, but I read in Stack Overflow question [SSH and Telnet library for java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432896/ssh-and-telnet-library-for-java) that JSch also supports Telnet.

Is this correct? And if so, could some one provide a small example?

Comment: This contains what looks like a telnet connection class using JSch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146991/ssh-telnet-on-jsch

Comment: Thanks for the link man, but unfortunately that is a ssh connection with the port 22 number instead of 23 for telnet.

Comment: @Belove That code opens an SSH shell session and runs a `telnet` command on the remote server. So it actually does not implement the Telnet protocol. It just runs the `telnet` command. I've edited the post to make it clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSch is an SSH library.

Quoting [the JSch web page](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/):

> JSch is a pure Java implementation of **SSH2**.

No mention on Telnet.

---

Also, there's no mention of the "telnet" or "23" in the JSch source code.

The only classes that connect anywhere (= use `Socket` Java class) are `Session` (SSH), `Proxy*` and `ChannelForwardedTCPIP` (port forwarding) and `ChannelX11`.

Comment: cool thanks man. if anyone is wondering what library to use for telnet in java apache have a library that i'm using now and it seems to work fine.